# call function in controller asp.net mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

i have a function in controller. name is reportController to return a chart

```
public FileContentResult GetChart(DateTime tuNgay, DateTime denNgay)
    {
        return File(Chart(tuNgay, denNgay), "image/png");
    }
```

and function Chart(tuNgay, denNgay)
now i want call them from view

```
<div><img src="/report/GetChart" />
```

but i get error 
please help me

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: You can try `<img src="@(Url.Action("GetChart", "report"))" />`

Comment: I see, you need to also provide the two datetime paramters: try with `<img src="@(Url.Action("GetChart", "report", new { tuNgay = someDate,  denNgay = someOtherDate}))" />`

Comment: Does the function `Chart(tuNgay, denNgay)` return the result as image bytes?

Comment: yes, i can do it. thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You could use `@Url.Action`

```
<img src='@Url.Action("GetChart","report")' />
```